# LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING animations don't run when removing child views

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a `FrameLayout` container that I'm trying to have animate it's changes.  I call `container.setLayoutTransition(layoutTransition)` on the view, but when I later call `container.removeView(v)` the `DISAPPEARING` animation isn't executed, the view is simply immediately removed.

Here's my code for the transition:

```
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = new LayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING,
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(null, View.TRANSLATION_Y, toolHeight, 0f));
layoutTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, 0);
layoutTransition.setDuration(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, 1000);
layoutTransition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING,
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(null, View.TRANSLATION_Y, 0f, toolHeight));
layoutTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, 0);
layoutTransition.setDuration(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, 1000);
container.setLayoutTransition(layoutTransition);
```

And to swap views I do this:

```
if (container.getChildCount() > 0) {
  for (int i = container.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    container.removeViewAt(i);
  }
}
container.addView(newView);
```

I've slowed down the animations to confirm the situation, and I can clearly see that the `APPEARING` transition is executed appropriately, but the `DISAPPEARING` transition isn't, the view is simply removed immediately.

I've found that if I remove the view from the `LayoutTransition.removeChild()` method it works, but that adds quite a bit of complexity that doesn't seem necessary.  Here's what that becomes:

```
if (container.getChildCount() > 0) {
  final View v = container.getChildAt(0);
  container.getLayoutTransition().removeChild(container, v);
  container.getLayoutTransition().addTransitionListener(new LayoutTransition.TransitionListener() {
    @Override
    public void startTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {
    }

    @Override
    public void endTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {
      transition.removeTransitionListener(this);
      if (transitionType == LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING) {
        container.removeView(view);
      }
    }
  }
}
container.addView(newView);
```

Think that's bad?  That's only for removing a single view at a time, if there is more than one view in the container then I've got to add a transition listener that counts executions to know when to remove itself, and that's just a mess.

The removing itself is interesting, because if I simply put that transition listener on the `LayoutTransition` and it doesn't remove itself, then the disappearing transition doesn't run again.

Clearly I'm missing something pertaining to making the remove transition execute.  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

It's been pointed out to me that adding views cancels the `DISAPPEARING` transitions:

```
public class ViewGroup {
  private void addViewInner(...) {
    if (mTransition != null) {
      // Don't prevent other add transitions from completing, but cancel remove
      // transitions to let them complete the process before we add to the container
      mTransition.cancel(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING);
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Wonder what the reasoning is here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noticed, `LayoutTransition` doesn't really sequence animation types the way some of the newer APIs do. It's designed to handle a single item change at a time. The cleanest code will come from sequencing the add yourself with a delay, rather than chaining listener calls:

```
if (container.getChildCount() > 0) {
  for (int i = container.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    container.removeViewAt(i);
  }

  //Start the add once removals are complete
  long duration =
    container.getLayoutTransition().getDuration(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING);
  container.postOnAnimationDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
      container.addView(newView);
    }
  }, duration);
} else {
  container.addView(newView);
}
```

You might get better choreography out of [Scenes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Scene.html) for something like this, but that is API 19+

Comment: If I've got to do that, would it be better to 'schedule' the add using an auto-removing LayoutTransitionListener?

Comment: The difficulty with that, as you mentioned, is having to cascade the removal listeners or count transactions to know when they are all complete. This is a way of getting "close enough" with much less code.